# When can a characteristic curve (here an amplifier) be considered linear?

Tags: measurement, linear

I have built a difference amplifier and I have a pretty linear characteristic with a coefficient of determination of 0,9999478 (by a linear regression). Is it enough to say it's "pretty linear" (I don't want to make a bold claim but it's not very important in my paper) ?

The difference amplifier is for measurement and control in a DC DC converter. The amplification is approximately 100 times the input value, and the values should be used for stability analysis.

Comment: Well we need more information about your paper. How exactly would the non-linearity affect the conclusion? What values did other researchers from your field accept as linear enough and in what circumstances?

Comment: When it becomes a characteristic "line" ;-)

Comment: It becomes linear when the marketing people get involved.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it backwards.  You spec how linear you need it to be, and then design to it.

You're also not measuring linearity the way most folks do. If x is your input, and y is your output, nonlinearity is maximum HORIZONTAL distance from the full scale best fit line as a percentage of full scale.

Comment: That is, I deed, how I did it, but I'm just saying "seems ok to me". That's why I wanted to know I there are standards for this.

Comment: Not that I know of.  There are standards for how to measure nonlinearity in various device classes, like IEC 60904-10 for photovoltaics, but I don't know of any defining a threshold.